# Is the " npm run watch" property already in Laravel Vite?

Tags: laravel, npm, alpine.js, laravel-vite

Is the "watch" property already in vitejs?
I'm starting a new project using Laravel Framework 9.19.0 in which vite is auto-mounted.
I've added alpine.js for the front. I've tried to run

> npm run watch

This is my package.json file

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "watch": "npm-watch",                       <-<=-----I've added this line------->
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.25",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "vite": "^2.9.11"
},
"dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^3.10.2"
}
```

}

and the following error occurred.

```
   0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.17.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Arotiana's\laravel9_portfolio\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\flutter\bin;C:\Users\Arotiana's\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Arotiana's\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Arotiana's\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\PHP;C:\Users\Arotiana's\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Arotiana's\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin;C:\windows\System32;C:\flutter\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: C:\Users\Arotiana's\laravel9_portfolio
10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm-watch' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `npm-watch`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Arotiana's\laravel9_portfolio
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v14.17.6
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ watch: `npm-watch`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can you help me??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can replace your "scripts" by this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "watch": "vite build --watch"
},
```

And you can run `npm run watch`

Comment: when i have some typescripts in the input files the watcher just hangs :(

Comment: @user151496 did you try only use `npm run dev`?

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 10 here**

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#running-vite) states that you can run:

`npm run dev`

And it will perform the same behaviour as a watch, however, when wrapping up your work, you should then run:

`npm run build`

---

*docs excerpt:*

> There are two ways you can run Vite. You may run the development server via the dev command, which is useful while developing locally. The development server will automatically detect changes to your files and instantly reflect them in any open browser windows.
>
> Or, running the build command will version and bundle your application's assets and get them ready for you to deploy to production: